# Error occur when I am building my app.(Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.)

Tags: android, flutter, metadata, execution, build-error

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-beta01.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Lara!b.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\56c0cb97790e9054921ec81d\jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0-beta01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.7.0-beta01.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\Lara!b.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ad49c3e20e28519b53\core-1.7.0-beta01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in case you are facing this problem after running code from a cloned repository on GitHub:

Step 1 : Create a new flutter project at your local system

Step 2 : Copy the code given in `main.dart` file of stub project and paste it into `main.dart` file of your local project

Step 3 : Make an 'assets' folder in your local project

Step 4 : download asset-files from GitHub and put them into your local 'assets' folder

Step 5 : in your local `pubspec.yaml` file, add dependency for your 'assets' folder

Step 6 : Rename `MyApp()` in widget testing file to `MaterialApp()`

Checkout my full answer here for an almost same question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71882107/18520267

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. This help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `minCompileSdk` in `/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties` to 30

Comment: I already changed it but still this error comes when I build my project.
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction

Comment: how about your build.grade? did you change that as well? When you are there, set compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion to 30 just to make sure. After that, maybe try invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: I changed it to 30 but I get an error of depreciated apis.  Thanks for your opinion.