# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata

Tags: flutter

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
> dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
> is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
> Dependency: androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-rc01.
> AAR metadata file: C:\Users\100812.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\8fcba37f766c3622d8dbd30df4e98577\work-runtime-2.7.0-rc01\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

Comment: Hello, Can you share build.gradle file

Comment: what you are trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the compileSdkVersion under: `android > app > build.gradle`

```
android {

  compileSdkVersion 31

  ...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
android {

  compileSdkVersion 33

  ...

}
```

You can got error with the version 31, it’s not works, try this
it's works for me .

Answer (score 0):

Check with your configuration in android/app/src/build.gradle file
with new version of flutter compileSdk and targetSdkVersion are mention as below

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
.....  
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue, In case you cloned a GitHub repository and then when you run that code this is the error that comes up(as it happened with me) then Solution :

Step 1 : Create a new flutter project at your local system

Step 2 : Copy the code given in `main.dart` file of stub project and paste it into `main.dart` file of your local project

Step 3 : Make an 'assets' folder in your local project

Step 4 : download asset-files from GitHub and put them into your local 'assets' folder

Step 5 : in your local `pubspec.yaml` file, add dependency for your 'assets' folder

Step 6 : Rename `MyApp()` in widget testing file to `MaterialApp()`

Hit save(in files other than `pubspec.yaml`), get all dependencies(in `pubspec.yaml`) and you're good to go

In short :
Copy the required code and the dependencies you want
Then Save the changes and run

Error was there in my case mainly because the Flutter V2 has many changes and the code was outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to android/app/build.gradle

Change:
From: compileSdkVersion 29
To: compileSdkVersion 31

Answer (score 0):

Please run, then press **f** you will notice the SDK is the wrong version.
npx react-native doctor