# How to increase the compile sdk version

Tags: flutter

Actually,the `minCompileSdk` is 31, but the `minSdkVersion`is significantly lower.  I have to increase the`compileSdk`of my project  .
I got to know about it by looking at the this error,
Also the link to the above explanation,[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374270/execution-failed-for-task-appcheckdebugaarmetadata).

So I wanted to know how to increase the `compileSdk` of my project.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window-java:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: /home/manish/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/625039eaad011f884ddd84f857a44b7f/jetified-window-java-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
      > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
        dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
        is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
        Dependency: androidx.window:window:1.0.0-beta04.
        AAR metadata file: /home/manish/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/a78fdf90e4c1f8464b19895cfb365f3f/jetified-window-1.0.0-beta04/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can find the compileSdkVersion under: android > app > build.gradle

```
android {

  compileSdkVersion 31

  ...

}
```

Comment: Now getting an error which to update,`ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>

Comment: then please update the Kotlin version. PS: this also means that my answer was correct

Comment: Yes,its correct  and so I upvoted you

Comment: thank you and please you can accept my answer also